# PL/SQL Trigger not displaying?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, database-trigger

So the simple code im trying to test is this:

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dml_stud
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON studenti
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('DML change in table students !');

  CASE
     WHEN INSERTING THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERT');
     WHEN DELETING THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
     WHEN UPDATING THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATE');
     -- WHEN UPDATING('NAME') THEN .... 
  END CASE;
END;
/

delete from students where id=10000;
```

This is the output that I'm getting:

```
Trigger DML_STUD compiled


0 rows deleted.
```

Shouldn't the 'DELETE' text besomewhere before or after the "0 rows deleted" text ?

I'm using the latest version of Oracle SQL Developer, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are checking for output in wrong place.

Go to View-> Dbms Output

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with your code, except for a typo for table name which should be `students` instead of `studenti`. You may use this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dml_stud
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON students
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DML change in table students !');

  CASE
    WHEN INSERTING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERT');
    WHEN DELETING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE');
    WHEN UPDATING THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('UPDATE');
  END CASE;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch from the GUI you currently use to good, old SQL*Plus, you'll notice that everything works as expected:

```
SQL> create table students as select * from emp;

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger dml_stud
  2     before insert or update or delete on students
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('DML change in table students !');
  5
  6    case
  7       when inserting then dbms_output.put_line('INSERT');
  8       when deleting  then dbms_output.put_line('DELETE');
  9       when updating  then dbms_output.put_line('UPDATE');
 10    end case;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> delete from students where ename = 'KING';
DML change in table students !
DELETE

1 row deleted.

SQL>
```